# como usar o DATA_FORMAT() no mySQL com C# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

eu preciso pegar os dados das datas e passar eles para o formato `dd/mm/AAAA`, pois ela vem assim do MySQL `AAAA-mm-dd` para depois passar para um databinder que está em um Repeater no front, alguém sabe como usar o `Data_Format()`? ou um outro recurso para trocar o formato? no meu mySQL todas essas datas estão com `string`, não sei se essa informação é relevante ou não.

```
private void CarregarPacientes()
{
    string query = @"select pac_id, pac_nome, pac_contato, pac_unidade, pac_dataMoldagem, pac_proteseProva, pac_entregaPac from pacientes";
    
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, Conexao.Connection);
        da.Fill(dt);
        //Popular o Repeater
        rptPacientes.DataSource = dt;
        rptPacientes.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblMsgPaciente.Text = "Falha: " + ex.Message;
    }
}
```

saida do DataBinder

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pac_dataMoldagem")%>
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pac_proteseProva") %>
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pac_entregaPac") %>
```

Comment: Deu certo a resposta?

Answer (score 1):

Para formatar a informação de qualquer formato e no caso para Data (dia, mês e ano) existe nesse mesmo método `Eval` uma sobrecarga onde pode ser feito assim um formato esperado `{0:dd/MM/yyyy}` como demonstrado no trecho:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
          <asp:Repeater ID="RptList" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
              <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "name") %>
              <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "created","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>
              <hr />
            </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

onde `created` é um campo na tabela do tipo `date`. <sup>***Referencia:*** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621373/how-do-i-change-the-date-format-of-a-databinder-eval-in-asp-net/7621831</sup>

No texto [Cadeias de caracteres de formato de data e hora personalizado](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) possui a tabela que explica o tipos de formatos permitidos para data ou data e hora:

```
+----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| "MM/dd/yyyy"                                 |  07/21/2007                          |
| "dddd, dd MMMM yyyy"                         |  Saturday, 21 July 2007              |
| "dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm"                   |  Saturday, 21 July 2007 14:58        |
| "dddd, dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm tt"                |  Saturday, 21 July 2007 03:00 PM     |
| "dddd, dd MMMM yyyy H:mm"                    |  Saturday, 21 July 2007 5:01         |
| "dddd, dd MMMM yyyy h:mm tt"                 |  Saturday, 21 July 2007 3:03 PM      |
| "dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"                |  Saturday, 21 July 2007 15:04:10     |
| "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"                           |  07/21/2007 15:05                    |
| "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt"                        |  07/21/2007 03:06 PM                 |
| "MM/dd/yyyy H:mm"                            |  07/21/2007 15:07                    |
| "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt"                         |  07/21/2007 3:07 PM                  |
| "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"                        |  07/21/2007 15:09:29                 |
| "MMMM dd"                                    |  July 21                             |
| "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK"     |  2007-07-21T15:11:19.1250000+05:30   |
| "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'"        |  Sat, 21 Jul 2007 15:12:16 GMT       |
| "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss"              |  2007-07-21T15:12:57                 |
| "HH:mm"                                      |  15:14                               |
| "hh:mm tt"                                   |  03:14 PM                            |
| "H:mm"                                       |  5:15                                |
| "h:mm tt"                                    |  3:16 PM                             |
| "HH:mm:ss"                                   |  15:16:29                            |
| "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"             |  2007-07-21 15:17:20Z                |
| "dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"                |  Saturday, 21 July 2007 15:17:58     |
| "yyyy MMMM"                                  |  2007 July                           |
+----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

---

O seu código também possui problemas, um código ideal segue:

```
void LoadRepeater()
{
    string sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM tests ORDER BY id";
    string connStr = "Server=localhost;Database=dbs;Uid=root;Pwd=senha;";
    using (MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
    using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sqlStr, connect))
    {
        connect.Open();
        using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            DataTable items = new DataTable();
            items.Load(reader);
            RptList.DataSource = items;
            RptList.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

utilizar um classe [MySqlDataAdapter](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataAdapter.htm) tem vários aspectos negativos, um deles é desempenho o outro é que essa classe faz muito coisa que não são necessários.

Comment: Obrigado por comentar no meu post!

```
string connStr = "Server=localhost;Database=dbs;Uid=root;Pwd=senha;";
```

já tem em uma outra parte do meu código, infelizmente ele não trocou o formato na minha lista

Comment: Como está armazenado esse data @FelipeBellini?

Comment: vem direto do banco, como varchar(10)

Comment: @FelipeBellini então cara não poderia ser assim, se o tipo de dado é data no banco tem que ser date, e por isso a sua pergunta em vez de trazer uma informação real, trouxe uma pegadinha. Na sua SQL faz assim: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date.asp tipo: `select pac_id, pac_nome, pac_contato, pac_unidade, date(pac_dataMoldagem), pac_proteseProva, pac_entregaPac from pacientes`

Comment: Vale lembrar @FelipeBellini que a data no banco sempre coloca  `date` isso que eu falei para você fazer é uma gambiarra criada por você Ok! A minha solução é correta quando o tipo é `date`, entendeu.